# Python Tkinter Window issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

While executing this program, one window name 'Test3' is opening and one button is showing. while pressing that button, another window is opening(def hider), but all the content is overwritten in existing window(Test3). How to put that window content in new window that is opening blank.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test3")

mylabel0= Label(root, text="—————→")
mylabel0.grid(row=0, column=0)
mylabel1= Label(root, text="Test3", font=500)
mylabel1.config(font=("segoe ui black", 20))
mylabel1.grid(row=0, column=1)
mylabel0= Label(root, text="←—————")
mylabel0.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

here is def hider function:

```
 def hider():
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import base64

    def decrypt():
        password = code.get()

        if password == "2929":
            screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
            screen2.title("decryption")
            screen2.geometry("400x200")
            screen2.configure(bg="#00bd56")

            message = text1.get(1.0, END)
            decode_message = message.encode("ascii")
            base64_bytes = base64.b64decode(decode_message)
            decrypt = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")

            Label(screen2, text="DECRYPT", font="arial", fg="white", bg="#00bd56").place(x=10, y=0)
            text2 = Text(screen2, font="Rpbote 10", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
            text2.place(x=10, y=40, width=380, height=150)

            text2.insert(END, decrypt)
        elif password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("encryption", "Password section is Empty")

        elif password != "2929":
            messagebox.showerror("encryption", "Invalid Password")

    def encrypt():
        password = code.get()

        if password == "2929":
            screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
            screen1.title("encryption")
            screen1.geometry("400x200")
            screen1.configure(bg="#ed3833")

            message = text1.get(1.0, END)
            encode_message = message.encode("ascii")
            base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(encode_message)
            encrypt = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")

            Label(screen1, text="ENCRYPT", font="arial", fg="white", bg="#ed3833").place(x=10, y=0)
            text2 = Text(screen1, font="Rpbote 10", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
            text2.place(x=10, y=40, width=380, height=150)

            text2.insert(END, encrypt)
        elif password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("encryption", "Password section is Empty")

        elif password != "2929":
            messagebox.showerror("encryption", "Invalid Password")

    def main_screen():

        global screen
        global code
        global text1

        screen = Tk()
        screen.geometry("400x500")

        screen.title("msg hider")

        def reset():
            code.set("")
            text1.delete(1.0, END)

        Label(text="Enter text for encryption and decryption:", fg="black", font=("segoe ui black", 13)).place(x=10,
                                                                                                               y=10)
        text1 = Text(font="Robote 20", bg="white", fg="black", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD, bd=0)
        text1.place(x=10, y=50, width=355, height=100)

        Label(text="Enter secret key for encryption and decryption:", fg="black", font=("segoe ui semibold", 13)).place(
            x=10, y=170)

        code = StringVar()
        Entry(textvariable=code, width=19, bd=0, font=("arial", 25), show="•").place(x=10, y=200)

        Button(text="ENCRYPT", height="2", width=23, bg="black", fg="white", bd=0, command=encrypt).place(x=10, y=250)
        Button(text="DECRYPT", height="2", width="23", bg="black", fg="white", bd=0, command=decrypt).place(x=200,
                                                                                                              y=250)
        Button(text="RESET", height="2", width="50", bg="#ed3833", fg="white", bd=0, command=reset).place(x=10, y=300)

        screen.mainloop()

    main_screen()

button_ebook= Button(root, text="Msg Hider", font=30, padx=25, pady=25, command=hider, fg="black", bg="white", borderwidth=1)
button_ebook.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using two instances of `tk.Tk()` which seems the root of this problem. Also make sure you calling `.mainloop()` as the last logical line in your code. Instead of creating a new window, you can use a new frame an pack it on the existing window.

Comment: I replace Tk() with Toplevel() and tried it plus did some changes, but still causing error, either old or new one. I'm new to coding, so, It'll be very appreciated if you can help in detail.

Comment: @Mandepp I would need to write a whole code and wouldnt know if you can use it, since you didnt provided a [mre]. Therefore even if I would write the code for you it may not help. So please update your question with the details needed and I will answer your question. All I can tell you right now is that your achitecture fail for some reason.

Comment: better show minimal working code which we can copy, run, and edit to create solution.

Comment: your main problem can be that you don't set `parent` in widgets -`Text(screen1,...)` - so it automatically uses `root` as parent.

Comment: if you create main screen `screen = Tk()` then you should use `screen..mainloop()` instead of `root.mainloop()`. You should hjave only one `Tk()` and only `mainloop()`

Comment: Thankyou very much @furas . It helps a lot.